# Delete method - conn |> put_status(:no_content) deletes record but returns error 500

Tags: controller, elixir, phoenix-framework

In controller I have delete method:

```elixir
def delete(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  user = conn.assigns.current_user
  book = Books.get_book!(id)

  with  true           <- book.user_id == user.id,
        {:ok, %Book{}} <- Books.delete_book(book) do
          conn
          |> put_status(:no_content)
          |> render("deleted.json")
  end
end
```

If conditions are fullfilled method deletes book from db but returns Internal server error 500.

I tried also
`|> put_status(204)`

but result was the same.

I wanted to check if it works when I put another status code. I've written
`|> put_status(:not_found)`

And It works. It shows delete.json and status 404 not_found correctly.

I deleted whole put_status and method returns json correclty but with status 200 OK. So basically only status 204 doesnt work in this case. I dont know why.

Thanks for help

Comment: What error was generated in the logs when you got the 500 error?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return `204 No Content` with a JSON response, which is obviously content. Instead of [`render/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#render/2), which will render a view, try [`send_resp/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#send_resp/3) directly:

```elixir
send_resp(conn, :no_content, "")
```

Comment: Actually it seems fair. Didnt think that way. Well clarified simple task, thank you :)